# Using mocks and death tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have found an unexpected behavior of Google Test, when it comes to death tests combined with expectations on mock objects.

Check the following example:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <cassert>

class Interface
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class InterfaceMock : public Interface
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(foo, void());
};

class Bar
{
public:
    void call(Interface& interface)
    {
        interface.foo();
        assert(false);
    }
};


TEST(BarTest, call_fooGetsCalledAndDies)
{
    InterfaceMock mock;

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo());

    ASSERT_DEATH({ Bar().call(mock); }, "");
}
```

Test fails because expected call to `mock.foo()` fails to assert:

```
Running main() from gmock_main.cc
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from BarTest
[ RUN      ] BarTest.call_fooGetsCalledAndDies

[WARNING] /tmp/tmp.sHHkM/gmock-1.7.0/gtest/src/gtest-death-test.cc:825:: Death tests use fork(), which is unsafe particularly in a threaded context. For this test, Google Test couldn't detect the number of threads.
foo.cc:31: Failure
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo())...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
[  FAILED  ] BarTest.call_fooGetsCalledAndDies (1 ms)
[----------] 1 test from BarTest (1 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (2 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] BarTest.call_fooGetsCalledAndDies

 1 FAILED TEST
```

Interestingly, if the `EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo())` line is commented, Google Mock raises a warning for an unexpected call to `mock.foo()`:

```
Running main() from gmock_main.cc
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from BarTest
[ RUN      ] BarTest.call_fooGetsCalledAndDies

[WARNING] /tmp/tmp.sHHkM/gmock-1.7.0/gtest/src/gtest-death-test.cc:825:: Death tests use fork(), which is unsafe particularly in a threaded context. For this test, Google Test couldn't detect the number of threads.

GMOCK WARNING:
Uninteresting mock function call - returning directly.
    Function call: foo()
Stack trace:
[       OK ] BarTest.call_fooGetsCalledAndDies (1 ms)
[----------] 1 test from BarTest (1 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

I guess this is somehow related to the warning on death tests using `fork()` and threads, but I fail to match all pieces together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known limitation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150801115151/https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#My_death_test_modifies_some_state,_but_the_change_seems_lost_aft) of death tests. Internally `assert_death` forks, so mocks called in the child are not registered in the parent process. If you wish to suppress the warnings, consider using `NiceMock`.

Comment: The point is that I do care about mocks getting called, so the test would be almost pointless. Could you provide a reference to the 'known limitation' statement? (just for the record)

Comment: @AntonioPérez I seem to recall reading about this on one of the mailing lists, but until I find a concrete statement, [check here](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#My_death_test_modifies_some_state,_but_the_change_seems_lost_aft). The point being that invokation of a mock function has the side effect of marking it as being called, which you don't see in the parent process.

Comment: I understand why I get unmet expectations as a consequence of `fork()`ing the process. But, why do I get the warning for unexpected call to mock objects then?

Comment: @AntonioPérez The expectation (the fact that the mock function should be called) is inherited by the child process. If you omit it, the child process will see the invocation to be unexpected. The fact that the function call is actually made however, is not passed back to the parent process. This is likely due to the fact that gtest stores information about calls in memory, which is not shared between parent/child processes.

Comment: So it's the child process who receives the unexpected mock function call, which is the one who dies. So I understand that the parent process should not run through a call to the mock function, hence shouldn't raise the warning message. I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: @AntonioPérez Unless I'm mistaken (a bit of `strace` could confirm), but it is the child process that sees the call as unexpected, and so it is the child that issues the warning.

Comment: Now I see, I thought it was only the parent output that was being printed, but now I understand that the printed lines are both the parent and child processes' output interleaved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As rightly answered above, the mock calls are not registered in the child process. You have to write your expect_calls inside the process. The following should works:

```
TEST(BarTest, call_fooGetsCalledAndDies)
{
    InterfaceMock mock;

    ASSERT_DEATH({ [](){ EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo());
                         Bar().call(mock);} , "");
}
```