# How to add expectations alongside with ASSERT_DEATH in GoogleTest for C++

Tags: c++, mocking, googletest

Given those interfaces:

```
class ITemperature
{
public:
    virtual ~ITemperature() = deafult;
    
    virtual int get_temp() const = 0;
};

class IHumidity
{
public:
    virtual ~IHumidity() = deafult;
    
    virtual int get_humidity() const = 0;
};
```

And this SUT:

```
class SoftwareUnderTest
{
public:
    SoftwareUnderTest(std::unique_ptr<ITemperature> p_temp,
                      std::unique_ptr<IHumidity> p_humidity)
    : m_temp{std::move(p_temp)}, m_humidity{std::move(p_humidity)}
    {}
    
    bool checker()
    {
        assert(m_temp && "No temperature!");
    
        if (m_temp->get_temp() < 50)
        {
            return true;
        }
        
        assert(m_humidity && "No humidity");
        
        if (m_humidity->get_humidity() < 50)
        {
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    
private:
    std::unique_ptr<ITemperature> m_temp;
    std::unique_ptr<IHumidity> m_humidity;
};
```

And this mocks:

```
class MockITemperature : public ITemperature
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(int, get_temp, (), (const override));
};

class MockIHumidity : public IHumidity
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(int, get_humidity, (), (const override));
};
```

I want to make a test that checks that `get_temp` is called and also that the second assert (the one that checks that the humidity is `nullptr`), but when a do this test, I get the assert, but I the expectation tells me that it's never called (but it is actually called once)

this is the test:

```
class Fixture : pu`blic testing::Test
{
protected:
    void SetUp() override
    {
        m_sut = std::make_unique<SoftwareUnderTest>(m_mock_temperature, m_mock_humidity);
    }
    
    std::unique_ptr<StrickMockOf<MockITemperature>> m_mock_temperature = std::make_shared<StrickMockOf<MockITemperature>>();
    std::unique_ptr<StrickMockOf<MockIHumidity>> m_mock_humidity;
    
    std::unique_ptr<SoftwareUnderTest> m_sut;
};

TEST_F(Fixture, GIVEN_AnInvalidHumidityInjection_THEN_TestMustDie)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(*m_mock_temperature, get_temp).Times(1);
    
    ASSERT_DEATH(m_sut->checker(), "No humidity");
}
```

Comment: I just found a possible solution (not sure if it's the best, adding this into a lambda (the expect and the method execution), and make the lambda to ASSERT_DEATH

Comment: Please when you are posting code as example of problem please make sure it doesn't have not related compilation error. Your have a lot: typos (for example `deafult`), logic errors and so on. Here is [my attempt to fix your example](https://godbolt.org/z/f7nE84xve) there is still problem with ownership of dependencies (mocks).

Comment: Other problem is `assert` macro! Note that `assert` doesn't do anything in release build, so your test is invalid! Test should work also for release builds!

Comment: Here is [version which compiles fine](https://godbolt.org/z/vdjj4dbMK) - test is failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a known limitation, see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150801115151/https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#My_death_test_modifies_some_state,_but_the_change_seems_lost_aft) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32459510/4885321).

From what I have managed to discover by experimentation so far:

If you can live with the error message about leaking mocks (haven't checked if it's true or a false positive, suppressing it by AllowLeak triggers the actual crash), it can be done by making the mocks outlive the test suite and then wrapping references/pointers to them in one more interface implementation.

```cpp
//mocks and SUT as they were
namespace
{
    std::unique_ptr<testing::StrictMock<MockIHumidity>> mock_humidity;
    std::unique_ptr<testing::StrictMock<MockITemperature>> mock_temperature;
}


struct MockITemperatureWrapper : MockITemperature
{
    MockITemperatureWrapper(MockITemperature* ptr_) : ptr{ptr_} {assert(ptr);}
    int get_temp() const override { return ptr->get_temp(); }
    MockITemperature* ptr;
};

struct Fixture : testing::Test
{
    void SetUp() override
    {
        mock_temperature
            = std::make_unique<testing::StrictMock<MockITemperature>>(); 
        m_mock_temperature = mock_temperature.get();
        // testing::Mock::AllowLeak(m_mock_temperature);
        m_sut = std::make_unique<SoftwareUnderTest>(
            std::make_unique<MockITemperatureWrapper>(m_mock_temperature), nullptr);
    }
    
    testing::StrictMock<MockITemperature>* m_mock_temperature;
    std::unique_ptr<SoftwareUnderTest> m_sut;
};

TEST_F(Fixture, GIVEN_AnInvalidHumidityInjection_THEN_TestMustDie)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(*m_mock_temperature, get_temp).WillOnce(testing::Return(60));
    ASSERT_DEATH(m_sut->checker(), "No humidity");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vKnP7TsrW

Another option would be passing a lambda containing the whole to ASSERT_DEATH:

```cpp
TEST_F(Fixture, GIVEN_AnInvalidHumidityInjection_THEN_TestMustDie)
{
    
    ASSERT_DEATH(
        [this] {
            EXPECT_CALL(*m_mock_temperature, get_temp)
                .WillOnce(testing::Return(60));
            m_sut->checker();
        }(), "No humidity");
}
```

Works, but looks ugly, see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/GdhcGdbPj).

Last but not least: one can use custom assert or replace`__assert_failed` function and throw from it (possibly some custom exception), then use ASSERT_THROW instead of ASSERT_DEATH. While I'm not sure replacing `__assert_failed` is legal standard-wise (probably not), it works in practice:

```cpp
struct AssertFailed : std::runtime_error
{
    using runtime_error::runtime_error;
};


void __assert_fail(
    const char* expr,
    const char *filename,
    unsigned int line,
    const char *assert_func )
{
    std::stringstream conv;
    conv << expr << ' '  << filename << ' ' << line << ' ' << assert_func;
    throw AssertFailed(conv.str());
}
```

Example: https://godbolt.org/z/Tszv6Echj

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make a test that checks that get_temp is called and also
> that the second assert (the one that checks that the humidity is
> nullptr), but when a do this test, I get the assert, but I the
> expectation tells me that it's never called (but it is actually called
> once)

First you have to understand how death test are working.

- Before executing code in a macro `ASSERT_DEATH` gtest forks test process so when death happens test can continue.
- Then forked process is executing code which should lead to process death.
- Now test process joins forked process to see result.

Outcome is that in one process `checker()` is executed and mock is invoked and in test process it is `checker()` is not invoked so also mock is not invoked. That is why you get an error that mock is not satisfied.

Now answer from `alager` makes mock eternal so missing expected call is not reported. And since code uses global state adding other tests will lead to some problems. So I would not recommend this approach.
After edit he moved `EXPECT_CALL` inside `ASSERT_DEATH` so now only forked process expects call, but this is not verified since process dies before mock is verified. So again I would not recommend this approach either.

---

So question is what you should do? IMO your problem is that you are testing to much of implementation details. You should loosen test requirement (drop `StrictMock` or make it even make it `NiceMock`). Still I find this a bit clunky. [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hhreaT5qq)

I would change code in such way that it is impossible to construct `SoftwareUnderTest` with `nullptr` dependencies. You can use [gsl::not_null](https://spectre-code.org/classgsl_1_1not__null.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be due to some tricky mechanism that is used in googletest to assert death (they mention creating a child process). I did not find a way to fix it correctly, but I found one (not so great) workaround:

```
SoftwareUnderTest(ITemperature* p_temp, IHumidity* p_humidity)  // changed signature to allow leaks, I guess you cannot really do it in the production
```

and then:

```
class Fixture : public testing::Test
{
public:
    Fixture(): m_mock_temperature(new MockITemperature), m_mock_humidity(nullptr) {}
    ~Fixture() {
        // Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations(m_mock_temperature);  // if I uncomment that, for some reason the test will fail anyway
        std::cout << "Dtor" << std::endl;
        // delete m_mock_temperature;  // if I delete the mock correctly, the test will fail
    }
protected:
    void SetUp() override
    {
        // m_sut.reset(new SoftwareUnderTest(m_mock_temperature.get(), m_mock_humidity.get()));
        m_sut.reset(new SoftwareUnderTest(m_mock_temperature, m_mock_humidity));
    }
    
    // std::unique_ptr<MockITemperature> m_mock_temperature;  // if I use smart pointers, the test will fail
    // std::unique_ptr<MockIHumidity> m_mock_humidity;
    MockITemperature* m_mock_temperature;
    MockIHumidity* m_mock_humidity;
    std::unique_ptr<SoftwareUnderTest> m_sut;
};

TEST_F(Fixture, GIVEN_AnInvalidHumidityInjection_THEN_TestMustDie)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(*m_mock_temperature, get_temp).Times(1).WillOnce(Return(60));  // this is to ensure to go over first check, seems you forgot
    ASSERT_DEATH(m_sut->checker(), "No humidity");
    std::cout << "after checks" << std::endl;
}
```

Sorry, that's all I could figure out for the moment. Maybe you can submit a new issue in [gtest github](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues) while waiting for a better answer.